# Can damage taken while in polymorph break concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph

A wizard uses *polymorph* to become a *Giant Ape*. The ape takes damage, but the damage does not spill over into the wizard's hit points. Can this damage break concentration (if they fail the DC 10 or half-damage constitution saving throw)?

Comment: @Momonga-sama Read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) post on how answering your own question is explicity encouraged.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Yes

From concentration (PHB 203):

> **Whenever you take damage** while you are concentrating on a spell, you must take a constitution saving throw to maintain your concentration.

*Emphasis mine*

Given that, while polymorphed, the wizard **is** the ape, damage taken by the ape counts under "whenever you take damage". Thus, the wizard must take a constitution save to maintain concentration (with the ape's constitution modifier).

Being polymorphed [does not break concentration](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/10/22/polymorph-concentration/).