# Does your spell save DC change on spells cast before you change your spell save DC?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

While reading through the [symbol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol) spell I noticed that the spell technically could stay on forever, and during this time the caster could get stronger and thus gain a higher spell save DC.

When rolling against the caster's spell save DC, do you need to roll against their current spell save DC or the one they had while casting the spell?

Comment: Related: "[Does the save DC of a spell decrease if the original spellcaster polymorphs on a later turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105855)"

Comment: Related: [Do the relevant stats of a creature summoned via a "Summon Creature Type"-style spell change, if your stats change after you summoned it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/194823/23547)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### RAW don't specify

This is very probably not specifically spelled out in the rules anywhere, but I would argue that it's the one they had when the spell was cast.

It is a permanent (until dispelled) effect, which (to me) means, that after casting it, the caster has no connection to it anymore. Indeed you have to choose all of the specifics (its trigger, effect...) of the spell at the time of casting and your spell slot is consumed at that time as well. Hence, the DC is also fixed at the time of casting, just like everything else.

This is my interpretation of it anyway; as I mentioned, rules don't (as far as I know) address this specifically.

Comment: +1. This also makes the most in-universe sense. Symbols cast by apprentice wizards are shoddy work, if they later become better wizards, their old spells they'd already cast don't suddenly become better. Not that likely with 7th level spells that you'd have apprentices casting them, but makes narrative sense if you extrapolate to other similar spells.